# Java CL compiling: Adding multiple JAR files

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the simplest way to compile some Java code via Command Line while including multiple JAR files. This is what I've most recently tried and it does not seem to work.

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/* ConfigToExcel.java
```

The error I'm getting is

```
javac: invalid flag: lib/FIRST_JAR_FILE.jar
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix to this issue but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Windows or Unix based? If it's Windows, try changing the / to a \.

Comment: Or use something like [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/), SBT, Maven, etc. And make sure there's no spaces in any of your lib's jar file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with straight quotes (") with the classpath:

```
-cp "lib/*"
```